React native with Expo font not loading custom fonts
I am currently trying to load custom fonts for my app. The fonts load correctly for iOS but I get the following error on Android
[Error: The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
I am using expo-font to load google fonts when the app starts up
using @expo-google-fonts/montserrat
Below is code snippet that is not working. Currently works fine for iOS app.
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts(fontsUtils.customFontsToLoad)

if (!fontsLoaded || fontError) {
    console.log('ERROR => ', fontError)
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: colors.black,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator color={colors.white} size={'large'} />
      </View>
    )
  }

here is the code for customFontsToLoad
const customFontsToLoad = {
  Montserrat_100Thin,
  Montserrat_200ExtraLight,
  Montserrat_300Light,
  Montserrat_400Regular,
  Montserrat_500Medium,
  Montserrat_600SemiBold,
  Montserrat_700Bold,
  Montserrat_800ExtraBold,
  Montserrat_900Black,
  Montserrat_100Thin_Italic,
  Montserrat_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  Montserrat_300Light_Italic,
  Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
  Montserrat_500Medium_Italic,
  Montserrat_600SemiBold_Italic,
  Montserrat_700Bold_Italic,
  Montserrat_800ExtraBold_Italic,
  Montserrat_900Black_Italic,
  Mulish_200ExtraLight,
  Mulish_300Light,
  Mulish_400Regular,
  Mulish_500Medium,
  Mulish_600SemiBold,
  Mulish_700Bold,
  Mulish_800ExtraBold,
  Mulish_900Black,
  Mulish_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  Mulish_300Light_Italic,
  Mulish_400Regular_Italic,
  Mulish_500Medium_Italic,
  Mulish_600SemiBold_Italic,
  Mulish_700Bold_Italic,
  Mulish_800ExtraBold_Italic,
  Mulish_900Black_Italic,
}

Have checked all the imports and seems to be set up correctly. Can some one shed some light as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

You have to load the Fonts first, In App.tsx maybe
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
            
let customFonts = {
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Black.otf'),
    'Inter-Medium': require('./assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Medium.otf'),
    'Inter-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Regular.otf')
};
    
// useEffect        
await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);

See Usage for details.
